# Property of intersections of Bochner spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces, interpolation-theory

My question:

Assume I have a function
$ u \in H^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$. 
Now I want to bound the gradient of $u$. Can I deduce that $u \in H^1(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ and under which requirements on $\Omega$ (smoothness of boundary?, dimension?, star shaped?) would this be true?
Does anyone have a clue how to approach this question?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works, by you can have a look on interpolation theory, e.g., the book by Tartar.